# Formula for Charging Capacitor in special diagram: Series + Parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

Given the following circuit:

[image]

First things first: Is the resistor, that is dashed and transparent, really necessary if the switch is in position **1**? If so, what are the formula for charging the capacitor?

Neglecting the half transparent Resistor, the current should be:

[image]

Since the Resistor on the left is parallel with the capacitor.

But how to include the Resistor that is in series? Here:

[image]

Comment: `Is the resistor, that is dashed and transparent, really necessary if the switch is in position 1?` In an electrical circuit the current exiting the source should return to its source. Hence the term "circuit". Without that resistor, there's no path for the current to return to the battery. So yes, it's necessary.

Comment: Remove the capacitor, and derive the Thevenin equivalent of the remaining circuit.

Comment: Maybe I_0 = 2*I_R + I_C ? Because the Resistors are in Series so they add up.

Comment: @Leon, the resistors are not in series.